# How to change Facebook link appearance on wall?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I've got website with creator - you can make your own character.

Character is generated in dynamic way via JS. After registration, character is saved on server. When user wants to check his character, he can use link from e-mail or find it in gallery. When user is using link, I'm taking data from url, getting data from server via AJAX and showing user his/her character.

Problem started when I wanted to implement Facebook's Like and Share buttons.
Whole content is generated in dynamic way and I have only access to client-side of project.

Share button is not a problem anymore because I'm using feed dialog so I can use dynamic data.

Problem is with Like button. Because of way how website works, I don't have webpages for every character with different Open Graph tags on server-side.

When new character is shown in gallery, I'm changing data-href atribute for Like button and calling FB.XFBML.parse(); to refresh data in button. Only static thing with generated character is image (every character has it's own image saved on server) so I'm using link to image for Like button. Button works fine, number of likes is shown in correct way.

But when someone is clicking Like button, on his/her facebook wall data is shown like this:

User xxx likes link: www.example.com/data/gallery/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.png

Is there any way (with FB JS SDK or FB App options / Open Graph Story) to change this data shown on wall? For example:

User likes: (title/name of Facebook App)

or something looking less ugly?

If not, if there is a way to change Open Graph meta tags for current character?

Comment: Create a unique URL that is shared. Like example.com/gallery.php?id=xxxxx and then add og-tags on that page

Comment: Like I said - I don't have access to server-side of project. It would be easy If I could do that.

Comment: You can use the Feed Dialog https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.4

Comment: I used it already to add share-like functionality to website. I just need to change how liked link on facebook looks like.